OpenSuse TW - Ignoring my custom keyboard layout
For a long time, I used a custom keyboard layout, working perfectly fine and being used as a default even after reboot. Now, I guess after an update/upgrade, it always defaults to my local language keyboard layout, even though I removed my language default from the available layouts in the system settings, where I also added my custom keyboard layout.
I defined the layout in a file called custom which is located in a directory in $HOME.
I then symlinked this file to a file in the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom directory.
Up until recently, it worked like a charm. I just can't figure out why it defaults back to another layout, even though the custom layout is still present in the system settings as the only layout.
After each reboot it appears that my localectl settings are changed back. Running localectl status gives me:
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
VC Keymap: de-nodeadkeys
X11 Layout: de
X11 Model: microsoftpro
X11 Variant: nodeadkeys
X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp

while I expect something like this:
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
VC Keymap: (unset)         
X11 Layout: custom

The 00-keyboard.conf file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ looks like this:
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "custom"
EndSection

One solution I had in mind, is to create a script which changes the layout to my custom one after a reboot, but that's another layer, which I really don't want to add to my system.
Since it is a custom layout with some major changes, I always lose my mind trying to type in my password. My blood pressure is off the charts.
